# Using MySQL With ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, elasticsearch, synchronization

I am using *MySQL* to store all of my data.
My application is *an e-commerce application* developed in *Node.JS*. It has many tables ( *users, sellers, stores, products, productoptions etc.* )

My goal now is to implement the ability to search for products and stores. I have been doing a lot of research on *Search Engines*, *Full Text Searches* etc.

After quite a lot of research, I decided to go with *ElasticSearch* to handle searching in my application. Now, I am well aware ElasticSearch has many features, but *I want to know how to utilize them best in this kind of application.*

In my opinion, I have *2 options*:

- Use *MySQL* alongside *ElasticSearch*. This, at least to me, sounds like the best option. The problem with this is *synchronizing MySQL and ES*. I did a lot of research about this topic, and found many methods, such as manually updating ES ( *once I perform a CRUD operation on MySQL, do the same thing for ES* ), or even use something like *go-mysql-elasticsearch*. Will these 2 even be good at performing such a task? *go-mysql-elasticsearch* doesn't seem too hard to implement but I am not sure if it's the way to go.
- Use ElasticSearch *as the main database*. Now, I know ElasticSearch is intended to mainly be used as a Search Engine, but it is indeed able to be used as a database. This would then *eliminate the problem* of having to sync MySQL and ElasticSearch. The biggest drawback with this method would be the fact that I would have to rewrite a lot of my code to switch from MySQL to ES entirely.

Since this is an e-commerce application the data will be updated often ( *adding new products, editing them, registering new users etc.* )
So to conclude, *which option should I go with?*
Is there a *third option?*

Comment: You can write a sync job using data integration tools such as [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) but then again that depends on amount of time you have because that again adds up some level of learning curve

Comment: Definitely looks interesting, I will look into it. Maybe there is a better way than using external programs? Also, Pentaho costs money, so I'm not sure how it compares to other alternatives.

Comment: I've been using option 1 for a couple of years, although I did it by putting a middleware that intercepted the mysql queries and ran the appropriate elasticseach query. Has worked out well.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what you used for putting the middleware in? Custom code, or?

Comment: That was mostly in-house code, but you might want to see: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html which comes close.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I will definitely look into it! Seems pretty straight forward as well.

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem you had (a table listing references, linked to a table of companies, ...). How did you manage to solve your problem ? Thanks